# Exibindo Modal com model passado dentro de um foreach em C# asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma página principal contendo uma lista de usuarios. Nessa lista de usuários eu tenho um botãozinho do lado onde vou clicar e exibir um modal, passando o model daquela linha que cliquei. Eu consegui fazer isso certinho, segue o resumo do codigo:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Usuario)
{
@Html.Partial("_comentario", item)
}
```

e o botão para chamar a partial

```
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#comentario">Comentário</a></li>
```

E ai tenho minha pagina modal (_comentario.cshtml) onde dentro dela quero ter um dado da model passada via partial.

Eu consigo passar certinho, porém o Modal está vindo sempre com o ultimo da lista dos usuários. Por exemplo, tenho uma lista com os usuarios 1, 2 e 3. Se eu clicar para exibir o comentario do Usuário 1, ele me trás o 3.

O que estaria errado? Esse modo de fazer está errado?

O código modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="comentario" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Adicionar Comentário</h4>
            </div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("AdicionarComentario", "Usuario", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
            {
            <div class="modal-body">        
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                           @Model.UsuarioId
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <label>Comentário</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="comentario" name="comentario" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar</button>
        </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Como está o código JavaScript que chama sua Modal?

Comment: @Cigano, estou chamando no link de um dropdownlist, através do data <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#comentario">Comentário</a></li>

Comment: Sim, mas qual JS ativa o modal?

Comment: Estou usando o bootstrap.js, versão 3.2.0
Uso o exemplo dado em http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, todas as modais possuem a seguinte construção:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="comentario" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Ou seja, todas as modais possuem o mesmo `id`.

`id` numa `div` é um atributo que precisa ser único, diferente de `class`, em que várias `div`s podem ser da mesma `class`. O ideal seria derivar as `divs` para `id`s únicos, como por exemplo:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="comentario1" ...
<div class="modal fade" id="comentario2" ...
<div class="modal fade" id="comentario3" ...
<div class="modal fade" id="comentario4" ...
```

Comment: Problema resolvido! Era isso mesmo.